# Creating polygon shapes via mouse drag does not center the shape to its selection border box

Tags: javascript, canvas, polygon, fabricjs

**Version**

1.7.3

**Test Case**

https://jsfiddle.net/human_a/twdgya93/

In this fiddle, I have also tried creating the shape using the following code to avoid creating empty polygons, but the result is the same:

```
const polygon = new fabric.Polygon(calcPolygonPoints(8, Math.abs( origX - pointer.x ) / 2 ), {
        objectCaching: false,
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        fill: 'rgba(255,255,255, 1)',
        perPixelTargetFind: false,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeDashArray: [0,0],
        objType: 'shape',
        stroke: 'rgba(17,17,17,1)',
        hasControls: false,
        hasBorders: false
    })
```

**Steps to reproduce**

Click on the green button to go to drawing mode, drag the mouse inside the canvas to start creating the shape, let go of the mouse, then try selecting the newly created shape. The bounding box size matches the size of the new polygon, but it's not positioned correctly.

**Expected Behavior**

If instead of polygons I try to create any other type of shapes (rectangles, circles or triangles) It works perfectly fine.

**Actual Behavior**

Since polygons use a different method by calculating the points it calculates the width and the height, and since in this method of creating shapes the width/height are being calculated after the shape is created (with mouse:move event) the bounding rectangle will not be positioned correctly.

Also even if I try to change the size of the polygon (I don't want to scale the shapes, it's a bad idea) again the bounding rectangle is not positioned correctly, you can try it in the demo above using the number input field right next to the button.

**PS**

I did not write the calcPolygonPoints function, I found it somewhere on the web a while ago, unfortunately, I could not find its link again to credit the creator of this amazing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a fiddle is very nice and fast to transform it in a working snippet, since then getting an answer is very easy.

Said so, the point is that the polygon in fabric.js do not support points updating. You were already calling the `_calcDimensions()` but that is not enough.

To correctly center the polygon in the bounding box you have to also populate its pathOffset property with updated values.

I added this in your snippet on the mouseUp event.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
var el = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
var drawPoly = document.getElementById('draw-poly');
var changeSize = document.getElementById('change-size');
var origX, origY;

var calcPolygonPoints = (sideCount,radius) => {
    var sweep=Math.PI*2/sideCount;
    var cx=radius;
    var cy=radius;
    var points=[]

    for(var i=0;i<sideCount;i++){
        var x=cx+radius*Math.cos( i*sweep )
        var y=cy+radius*Math.sin( i*sweep )
        points.push( { x:x, y:y } )
    }
    return(points)
}

canvas.initialize(el, {
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 width: 600,
 height: 600
});
canvas.renderAll();

drawPoly.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
 canvas.defaultCursor = "crosshair";
 canvas.selection = false;
 canvas.discardActiveObject();
 canvas.discardActiveGroup();
 canvas.forEachObject(object=>{ object.selectable = false; });
 canvas.renderAll();

 canvas.on('mouse:down', opt => {
  
  if (canvas.selection) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e)

  origX = pointer.x;
  origY = pointer.y;

  // I have also tried initial calculations here
  // by using calcPolygonPoints(8, Math.abs( origX - pointer.x ) / 2 ) instead of []
  // The result is the same
  const polygon = new fabric.Polygon(calcPolygonPoints(8, Math.abs( origX - pointer.x ) / 2 ), {
   objectCaching: false,
   left: origX,
   top: origY,
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center',
   fill: 'rgba(255,255,255, 1)',
   perPixelTargetFind: false,
   strokeWidth: 1,
   strokeDashArray: [0,0],
   objType: 'shape',
   stroke: 'rgba(17,17,17,1)',
   hasControls: false,
   hasBorders: false
  })
  // polygon._calcDimensions()
  canvas.add(polygon).setActiveObject(polygon)

 }).on('mouse:move', opt => {

  if (canvas.selection || !canvas.getActiveObject()) return;
  const newShape = canvas.getActiveObject()
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e)

  if (newShape) {
   newShape.set({
    points: calcPolygonPoints(8, Math.abs( origX - pointer.x ) / 2 )
   })
   newShape._calcDimensions()
  }
  changeSize.value = Math.abs( origX - pointer.x ) / 2;
  canvas.renderAll()

 }).on('mouse:up', opt => {
  // In my app I am using redux stores to turn off the drawing
  // Here I used the following if statement to turn off the drawing
  if (canvas.selection) return;

  const newShape = canvas.getActiveObject()
  if (newShape) {
   newShape.set({
    hasControls: true,
    hasBorders: true
   })
      newShape.pathOffset = {
        x: newShape.minX + newShape.width / 2,
        y: newShape.minY + newShape.height / 2
      };
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
      var center = { x: (pointer.x + origX)/2, y: (pointer.y + origY)/2}
      newShape.setPositionByOrigin(center, 'center', 'center')
   newShape.setCoords()
   canvas.renderAll()
  }
  canvas.renderAll()
  canvas.selection = true;

  canvas.off('mouse:down').off('mouse:move')
  canvas.defaultCursor = "default";
  canvas.discardActiveObject()
  canvas.forEachObject(object=>{
   if (object.evented)  object.selectable = true;
  })
 })
})

changeSize.addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
 if (!canvas.getActiveObject()) return;
 
 canvas.getActiveObject().set({
  points: calcPolygonPoints(8, parseInt(e.target.value, 10) )
 })
 canvas.getActiveObject()._calcDimensions()
 canvas.renderAll()
})
```

```css
button {
 border: 0 none;
 background: #2ecc70;
 border-radius: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 11px 22px;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 13px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 outline: 0 none;
}

input {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 box-shadow: none;
 padding: 11px;
 font-size: 13px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 max-width: 50px;
 outline: 0 none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 <canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
 <button id="draw-poly">Draw Polygon</button>
 <input type="number" id="change-size" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreaBogazzi, now it works. I put the ```newShape.pathOffset``` inside the ```mouse:move``` event to avoid the jumping when the shape is created. Also, does this mean that if I decide to change the size of the shape (without scaling) I have to run the ```newShape.pathOffset``` there too?

Comment: This sample is not running with the latest version of fabric js. What could be an issue?

Comment: let me see if i can update it in another answer with the lateat version